# Telerik MVC TreeView. How to expand all the nodes after ajax binding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc

TreeView gets populated through ajax and every item has `LoadOnDemand = true`. Now I need the tree to be fully expanded after binding. Calling `expand` on the client doesn't work because I guess `expand` doesn't support LoadOnDemand thing.

```
public ActionResult GetListOfDishes(TreeViewItem node)
        {
            var nodes = new List<TreeViewItem>();

            int dishId; int.TryParse(node.Value, out dishId);

            DataContext.GetDishes(dishId).ForEach(dish =>
                {
                    var d = new TreeViewItem
                    {
                        Text = dish.Name,
                        Value = dish.Id.ToString(),
                        LoadOnDemand = dish.IsGroup,
                    };
                    nodes.Add(d);
                });
            return new JsonResult { Data = nodes };
        }


 @(Html.Telerik().TreeView()
        .Name("DishesTree")
         .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Enabled(true).Select("GetListOfDishes", "Dining"))
                .ExpandAll(true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use the [client-side events](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/clientsideapi) (onDataBound) and then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function expandTree(e) {
        var treeview = $("#DishesTree").data("tTreeView");
        treeview.expand();
    }
</script>

<% Html.Telerik().TreeView()
        .Name("DishesTree")
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Enabled(true).Select("GetListOfDishes", "Dining"))
        .ClientEvents(c => c.OnDataBound("expandTree")) %>
```

Comment: I'm telling you it doesn't work. And probably because, right after the first bind it contains root elements, but not the Children, they yet  have to be loaded 'on demand'

Comment: Did you call it in the OnDataBound event?  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Oh...I see my mistake... Gosh... I had to drop .ExpandAll(true), because clientside expand() tries to do its work, and the tree is technically already expanded, so it collapses back